# list folder only if .\folder\QUERIES.INFO matches with %q%

Tags: batch-file, directory

i am trying to get the folowing script to work:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (listoffolders.txt) DO (
set "a="
set /p a=< .\%%G\QUERIES.INFO
call set qa=%%a:%q%=%%
if not "X%a%"=="X%qa%" echo:%%G>>listofmatches.txt
)
```

but it lists every folder instead of listing every folder if part of the first line of .\folder\QUERIES.INFO matches with %q%....

what am i doing wrong? could someone help me please?

Comment: `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, `Set "qa=!a:%q%=!"` and 
`If  /I Not "X!a!"=="X!qa!"` might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my comments, improved a little and put together as an answer:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(For /F "Delims=" %%G In (listoffolders.txt) Do (Set "a="
    Set /P "a="<"%%G\QUERIES.INFO"
    If /I Not "X!a!"=="X!a:%q%=!" Echo:%%G))>listofmatches.txt
```